# How to write a count of rows in a dataframe to JSON files?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a requirement where i need to filter data-frame and then write the count of rows returning to a separate json file.
I am filtering data-frame in following way :

```
 dfJson.where((col("Level") == "Medium")).select(dfJson["*")
```

I can get a count with count function as :

```
print(dfJson.count())
```

> How to save this count value to text or json file?

Answer (score 0):

you can use default python function to write to file

```
f = open("test.txt", "a")
f.write(dfJson.count())
f.close()
```